# Software Testing-- orthagonal array Testing algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, testing, orthogonal

Can anyone provide an optimized algorithm for orthogonal array testing. ? or any link to any relevant page will be also helpful..

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Hey.
Not sure what you mean in your question. In general orthogonal arrays are mathematical construct that has many uses in science/engineering.

In Software testing it used to reduce number of test cases you need to verify behavior that is based on some parameters. In particular [all pairs testing or pairwise testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pairs_testing) is technique most commonly used. Idea is that instead of all possible combination of parameters values you verify all possible pairs of parameters values. For example if you have behavior that takes 3 parameters, each parameter 3 possible values it gives you 27 possible combinations. Theory behind pairwise testing says that you will need to check only 9 combinations to find defects related to this data.

If you want to read about this, I would suggest [this post](http://www.developsense.com/pairwiseTesting.html). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pairs_testing) also provides [this one](http://www.mcdowella.demon.co.uk/allPairs.html). 
Some lists of orthogonal arrays can be found [here](http://www.york.ac.uk/depts/maths/tables/orthogonal.htm) and [here](http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts723.html).

[**edit**]
So, as per comment, to focus more on algorithm, I would start with (again) [this link](http://www.mcdowella.demon.co.uk/allPairs.html). Proceed with [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.147.2164&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and [this list of tools](http://www.pairwise.org/tools.asp). [Simple google search](http://www.google.pl/search?q=pairwise+testing+algorithm) then, I guess.

In the end you should have enough material, write one on your own.

Comment: hii, thanks a lott for the reply.. but i have an idea of what orthogonal array testing is about. what i wanted to know is that what algorithms can be used to do orthogonal testing.. i mean to say that what algo can be follow to generate the least number of test cases while checking for pairwise combination.. there are some tools available in the net. but they dont seem to explain the algorithms they are using so as to generate optimized number of test cases.